# Angular Login details hide from the request payload

Tags: angular

I am using Angular version 10 for my project. This is the my login function

```
    onLoggedin() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginModel).subscribe(

      data => {
        if (data) {
          console.log("Logged")
          this.router.navigate(['/reserve']);
        } else {
          console.log("No :(")
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }

      },
      error => {

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    );
    this.authService.notify({ isRefresh: true });

  }
```

this is the my service class

```
    login(credential: AuthLoginInfo): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(credential)
    return this.apiService.post('/authenticate', false, credential)
      .pipe(
        tap(token => this.doLoginUser(credential.username, token.jwt)),
        mapTo(true),
        catchError(error => {
          return of(false);
        }
        ));
  }
```

all things working well. but my problem is, when i log in to the system, username and password can view using network tab. is this issue or ? how i prevent from this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The submitted form / POST data will be readable by the browser where it was entered. This is the reason why any credential transmission from client to server needs to take place over an encrypted channel.See for example this [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/stable/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/04-Authentication_Testing/01-Testing_for_Credentials_Transported_over_an_Encrypted_Channel) reference.

The login will be plain text at the local browser -> encrypted with TLS when transmitting to server -> decrypted by server once received. This prevents any network snooping from retrieving the username and password in clear text.

The HTTPS transport would be handled by the web server engine or reverse proxy.